# Curl trying to get contents but capturing load page

Tags: wget, curl

help

https://workflowy.com/s/CbqM.M3tcZFhqd3#/?q=ADM-NF01

I am trying to capture

Feature Roadmap
V0 - Alpha
Basic A11Y and I18N
Foundations for Accessibility and Internationalisation
ADM-NF01

But all I seem to be capturing is The Loading screen

Capture=`time (curl -s -G -L --connect-timeout 100 https://workflowy.com/s/CbqM.M3tcZFhqd3#/?q=ADM-NF01)`

Only really interested in this line V0 - Alpha to capture this can change (versioning)

is there a way to do this tried curl and wget but no luck

Comment: The data itself is being loaded and displayed using JavaScript (you can check this by disabling JavaScript in your browser when following the link, or using an extension to block script execution).  Unfortunately, the only way I know of for handling this is to figure out where script is loading the data fro, and then fetch that instead.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off pulling from: 
https://workflowy.com/get_initialization_data?share_id=CbqM.M3tcZFhqd3&client_version=18

As @AustinHemmelgarn suggested, that page is build from javascript.  Ultimately, the actual data appears to come from the link I posted as part of the page.  You'll need to do some JSON parsing and extract the relevant info... but there ya go.

Comment: Think this is going to be beyond my skill

Comment: cant even curl that https://workflowy.com/get_initialization_data?share_id=CbqM.M3tcZFhqd3&client_version=18 or wget it

Comment: make sure you escape it.  The "&" is caught by bash & thrown into the background.  i.e. `curl "https://workflowy.com/get_initialization_data?share_id=CbqM.M3tcZFhqd3&client_version=18"`